# comparing differences between groups with cox regression in R - anova?

Tags: r, anova, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have constructed a cox regression:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(`infection time`, infection) ~ Treatment + 
    Gender + Race + Surface + head + buttock + trunk + up.leg + 
    low.leg + resp.tract, data = BurnData)
```

The p-value for the overall tests (likelihood, Wald and score) is only significant for the Likelihood ratio test. These test evaluate $H_0$: all $\beta$ = 0. The test statistics are not in an agreement, therefore the null hypothesis cannot be clearly rejected. Overall, the model doesn't have a good fit.

I want to learn about the covariate treatment, specifically I want to know if there is **significant difference in time until infection for the two treatment groups**?. From the output above I can say that the covariate is significant, but that is not the same right?

I have tried the `strata` command:

```
coxph(formula = Surv(`infection time`, infection) ~ strata(Treatment) + 
    Gender + Race + Surface + head + buttock + trunk + up.leg + 
    low.leg + resp.tract, data = BurnData)

  n= 154, number of events= 48 

                coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)  
Gender     -0.649207  0.522460  0.396943 -1.636   0.1019  
Race        1.997690  7.372010  1.016640  1.965   0.0494 *
Surface     0.003237  1.003243  0.009704  0.334   0.7387  
head       -0.082786  0.920548  0.344487 -0.240   0.8101  
buttock     0.560418  1.751404  0.421308  1.330   0.1835  
trunk       0.239397  1.270483  0.494814  0.484   0.6285  
up.leg     -0.432832  0.648669  0.375035 -1.154   0.2485  
low.leg    -0.164111  0.848648  0.373298 -0.440   0.6602  
resp.tract  0.077946  1.081065  0.351205  0.222   0.8244  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

           exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
Gender        0.5225     1.9140    0.2400     1.137
Race          7.3720     0.1356    1.0051    54.069
Surface       1.0032     0.9968    0.9843     1.023
head          0.9205     1.0863    0.4686     1.808
buttock       1.7514     0.5710    0.7670     3.999
trunk         1.2705     0.7871    0.4817     3.351
up.leg        0.6487     1.5416    0.3110     1.353
low.leg       0.8486     1.1783    0.4083     1.764
resp.tract    1.0811     0.9250    0.5431     2.152

Concordance= 0.67  (se = 0.066 )
Rsquare= 0.098   (max possible= 0.909 )
Likelihood ratio test= 15.89  on 9 df,   p=0.06912
Wald test            = 10.44  on 9 df,   p=0.3157
Score (logrank) test = 12.71  on 9 df,   p=0.1761
```

However, now the Treatment variable is not there at all. How can i compare if the two different group have significantly different effect on time to infection?

I have also tried anova `comparison`. Is the following a valid approach?

```
fit_trt0 <- coxph(Surv(`infection time`,infection) ~ (Treatment==0) + Gender + Race + Surface + 
                   head + buttock + trunk + up.leg + low.leg + resp.tract, data=BurnData)
summary(fit_trt0)

fit_trt1 <- coxph(Surv(`infection time`,infection) ~ (Treatment==1) + Gender + Race + Surface + 
                   head + buttock + trunk + up.leg + low.leg + resp.tract, data=BurnData)
summary(fit_trt1)

anova(fit_trt0,fit_trt1)
```

Comment: Using strata is not the correct approach. You could use strata for a covariate in which you had no particular interest but not when it is the focus. The rms package has an anova for its survival models.  Or you build your own by comparing the deviance for models with and without treatment. The second option you suggest is also not valid.